# Single Entry Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen

Me and my husband were granted single entry schengen visa and our country of entry and exit will be Italy. We are travelling in August, 2016 and are confused by what actually single entry means. We are also planning to visit other countries like Switzerland and Germany and back to Italy to fly back home.

Our understanding was, we can enter schengen area once ( in this case through Italy) and if we don't go outside the schengen regions (that includes all 22 countries) it will cause no problem even if we try to enter one country more than once.

Please can one clarify this to me? Thanks a lot.

Marina

Comment: Its a duplicate. But the answer is yes you can visit Germany and Switzerland and other countries in the Schengen area.

Comment: You are correct.  The single entry is a single entry into the Schengen area.  Crossing internal borders does not constitute entry into the Schengen area.  In other words, going from one Schengen country into another is not an entry for the purpose of a Schengen visa.

Comment: Important note: Some countries within the Schengen area are currently operating border controls, where your documents will be inspected. *Even here*, you are fine with the single entry as you will not be making a new entry to the area.